# Express.js — res.send() on RabbitMQ event during HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, rabbitmq

I'm doing user registration on my site.

```
exports.regitser = (req, res)->
  user = 
    unique_id : "RANDOM_HASH"
    name      : escape(req.body.name)
    pass      : escape(req.body.pass)
    ...

    # registrations starts here
```

In this moment I need to push data to RabbitMQ exchange, and wait for reponse in separate queue `"reg_results"`. After I get message in `"reg_results`" with `unique_id="RANDOM_HASH"`, it seems registration **for this user (for this HTTP-request)** completed successfully and now I can `res.send("You are registered!")` to client.

What is the best way to handle this pattern in a context of continuing HTTP-request from client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward. The main thing you need to understand is that `register(req,res)` *does not have to* provide result to res when function finishes. The result can be sent any time later. So, for your code it would be something along the lines

```
exports.register = (req, res)->
  user = 
  ...
  # registrations starts here
  //send your registration message here
  app.resultsQueue.subscribe (msg) ->
     if (msg is mine) res.render(msg)
```

It probably makes sense to use some kind of [Promise](https://github.com/bellbind/using-promise-q) with timeout (in the case registration message does not arrive within given time) to make the code neater.

Then your code would be (I will switch to JavaScript)

```
# registrations starts here
var deferred = Q.defer();
deferred.promise.timeout(5000).then(function (msg) {
   if (typeof msg == "Error")
      //handle timeout 
   else 
      res.render(msg)
});
app.resultsQueue.subscribe (function(msg) {
     if (msg is mine)  deferred.resolve(msg);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this not a problem, I will create a new subscription for `exchange` for every HTTP-event? This is my primary headache.

Comment: It depends on whether you need to optimize for the high volume of registrations. I would not worry too much initially, but do not forget to unsubscribe after timeout or when you receive your registration. Alternatively you could subscribe to RabbitMQ on the app level and handle the list of currently waiting responses yourself. But the rule is: make it work first, optimize later.